# C To Download Zip File From GitHub

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I want to download a zip of a GitHub repository that does not have a zip.  It is only folders and files.  If I navigate to the URL in my web browser it will download a zip and if I use wget url it will download a zip, but executing the below C script will not download a zip file for me.

Why will this script not download the zip file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://github.com/miketheknight2016/SXOS_Cheats/archive/master.zip");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it do instead of downloading a zip?

Comment: @immibis - the code executes and in the run window of CLion it prints the directory names, but I never have a .zip file downloaded.  Or an error thrown

Answer (score 1):

If you don't tell curl where to save the file it downloads, it will print it out in the console. What you're seeing is a zip file printed out in the console.

If you want it to save the output to a file, you have to create a function that writes a bunch of data to the file, and tell curl to use that function using CURL_OPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURL_OPT_WRITEDATA:

```
// before main
static size_t write_data_to_file(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
}

// in main before curl_easy_perform
FILE *file = fopen("myfile.zip", "wb");
// you should probably check if file is null here - that would mean it failed to open the file
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);

// in main after curl_easy_perform
fclose(file);
```

Don't ask me how this counts as "easy".

Comment: I get an error of curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed writing received data to disk/application